# refresh input after out of focus

Tags: html, angular

I have an input for an id that must be typed by the user. It should have a fix length of 7.
The user can enter an id like '1234' and I will add zero prefix to get the required legth.
My problem is that after the user types '1234' and gets out of focus, it's not displayed '0001234', it remains '1234'.

component variable

```
 let contact = {
      email: 'email@emai.com,
      id: Utils.addZeroPrefix(this.id.value, 7),
      name: 'name',
}

  idChanged() {
    this.idNotFound = false;
  }
```

Utils method

```
  public static addZeroPrefix(root, fixedLength) {
    while (root.length < fixedLength) {
      root = '0' + root;
    }
    return root;
  }
```

Html

```
  <input formControlName="id" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="id" aria-label="id" aria-describedby="id" (keyup)="idChanged()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `(blur)` you can append the extra zeros using `patchValue`

Try like this:

.ts

```
onBlur() {
   let id = this.contactForm.get("id");
   id.patchValue(this.addZeroPrefix(id.value, 7));
}
```

.html

```
<input type = "text"  formControlName="id" (blur)="onBlur()" >
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-mkonrp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**